# How can I prevent a variable from being used after a certain point?

Tags: javascript

```
function exampleFunction(){
    var theVariable = "Lol!";
    var variable2 = Lol.toLowerCase();
    console.log(theVariable);
    delete theVariable; //to prevent bugs, I want to ensure that this variable is never used from this point onward.
    console.log(theVariable); //This still prints "Lol!", even though I just tried to delete the variable.
}
```

In JavaScript, is it possible to prevent a variable from being used in a function after a certain point? I've tried declaring a string called `theVariable`, and then I tried to delete the variable using `delete theVariable`, but `console.log(theVariable)` still prints `theVariable`'s value even after that point.

I tried using `delete theVariable` to make `theVariable` unusable from that point onward (in order to prevent myself from accidentally using the variable when it is no longer needed), but it doesn't appear to have that effect. Is there any way to work around this limitation?

Comment: you can't use it outside of the function anyway, so when the function returns the var is gone. you can just set it to undefined, but the lexical name will always be carved out of the function's lexical scope.

Comment: @dandavis What does "it" refer to?

Comment: theVariable = undefined; is as close to what you want as it gets.

Comment: @dandavis Unfortunately, this still won't prevent theVariable from being set to another value after it is no longer needed.

Comment: so you want to retire the name?

Comment: Why do you need to make sure it never gets used again? You can't tell JS a variable is not valid.

Comment: @dtbarne I want to ensure that I won't accidentally use a variable after it is no longer needed inside a function. This could potentially lead to software bugs.

Comment: Then be sure to write the code so you don't...

Comment: Is there a jQuery plugin for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to limit its scope. Since JavaScript doesn't have block scope, that requires an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (or similar technique):

```
function exampleFunction(){
    var variable2;
    (function() {
        var theVariable = "Lol!";
        variable2 = Lol.toLowerCase();
        console.log(theVariable);
    })();
    // theVariable is now out of scope, and cannot be referenced
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In that case you can set the value to `undefined` like `theVariable = undefined`

The [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) function does not work as you expected

From docs

> The delete operator removes a property from an object.

In this case `theVariable` is not a property of an object, it is a variable in the current function scope.

Comment: The sentence you quoted is a bit misleading, since it's legal to apply `delete` to a variable, and its exact behavior can then depend on whether the variable is local or global, on whether it's inside an `eval` or not, and on what JS interpreter is running the code (e.g., what browser or browser version).

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't prevent the variable from being set to a non-undefined value - I prefer [ruakh's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17311333/975097).

Comment: @dtbarne no as ruakh said only gloabl variables fits that statement

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I didn't see OP was working with a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete primitive types, only objects. If you don't want to use a variable after a certain point, just review your code so that you don't use it. Unfortunately, JS does not have block scoping to restrict the visibility of variables. You'll have to check for this manually.

Alternatively, set the value to undefined.